# UIView autoresize on device rotation programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiview

I have a UIView (with multiple subviews) that I want to resize when the device (iPad) is rotated and I'm trying to use the autoresizingMask but I don't think I'm going about it the right way as it doesn't appear to be doing anything.

So in my init method for my view I'm doing the following. The frame for the view is the entire screen.

```
 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        self.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
                            UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
        self.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

        //Add in subviews, etc
    }
    return self;
}
```

And here is the code that initializes the view from my viewController:

```
MyViewClass *myView = [[MyViewClass alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height];
[self.view addSubview:myView];
```

Comment: Can you add the code for whatever is adding this view into your main frame?  The interaction between the view this view is enclosed in, is really what would determine how it resizes.

Comment: Just added the new code. it's a bit simplified but essentially that's what I'm doing.

Comment: When you do `UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame...` you initialize a UIView and not your view that contains the `initWithFrame` that you show. Is this exactly what you do, or is this the simplification you mention?

Comment: try insert myView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
                            UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but the view I'm initializing uses the initWithFrame method implementation shown above it and is a subclass of UIView. I just changed the code to reflect this. My simplification is simply that I just removed a lot of details for the sake of posting this question to just focus on the resizing aspect.

Comment: At first I thought you didn't initialize a `myView` but a `UIView`. Is your viewController's view also set to autoresize?